# How do I know that Entity Framework's Eager Loading is working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an entity with three separate child entities that all need to be loading in one hit to the database (typical eager loading scenario, I would imagine).

When I make the the call below:

```
public IQueryable<Participant> GetAllWithAllIncluded()
{
    dbSet.Include(p => p.EmailNotices).Load();
    dbSet.Include(p => p.EmailTemplatePlaceholders).Load();
    dbSet.Include(p => p.Actions).Load();
    return dbSet;
}
```

It makes the following entries in the SQL Profile:

```
SQL:BatchStarting   SELECT ...      
SQL:BatchCompleted  SELECT ...
SQL:BatchStarting   SELECT ...      
SQL:BatchCompleted  SELECT ...      
SQL:BatchStarting   SELECT ...      
SQL:BatchCompleted  SELECT ...
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
```

Does this mean that only one actual call/hit was made to the database in some soft of batch command?  Or is it making 4 separate hits?

When I remove the `.Load()` from the code, I get this in SQL Profiler:

When I make the the call below:

```
public IQueryable<Participant> GetAllWithAllIncluded()
{
    dbSet.Include(p => p.EmailNotices);
    dbSet.Include(p => p.EmailTemplatePlaceholders);
    dbSet.Include(p => p.Actions);
    return dbSet;
}
```

I get this in SQL Profiler:

```
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
```

**UPDATE 1**
Just to clarify, after the method returns, I tack on a few .Where() clauses and then I immediately .ToList() it.

**UPDATE 2**
As recommended, I'm including the where and list code:

```
List<Participant> participants = GetFilteredParticipants(repo, model, accountID).ToList();
```

And the function it calls:

```
private IQueryable<Participant> GetFilteredParticipants(ParticipantRepository repo, ParticipantRequestModel model, string accountID)
{

    IQueryable<Participant> participants = repo.GetAllWithAllIncluded();

    participants = participants.Where(p => p.Transaction.Account.AccountID == accountID || p.Transaction.Account.ParentID == accountID);

    if (model.ID != null)
    {
        participants = participants.Where(p => p.ID == model.ID);
    }
    if (model.ParticipantIdentifier != null)
    {
        participants = participants.Where(p => p.ParticipantIdentifier == model.ParticipantIdentifier);
    }
    if (model.TransactionID != null)
    {
        participants = participants.Where(p => p.TransactionID == model.TransactionID);
    }

    ... more wheres

    participants.Where(p => p.EmailNotices.Any(e => e.ParticipantID == p.ID)).Where(p => p.EmailTemplatePlaceholders.Any(e => e.ParticipantID == p.ID)).Where(p => p.Actions.Any(e => e.ParticipantID == p.ID));

    return participants;
}
```

Comment: You should update your question to include the adding of where clauses and ToList.

Comment: What do you get when you try `dbSet.Include(p => p.EmailNotices).Include(p => p.EmailTemplatePlaceholders).Include(p => p.Actions).Load();`?

Comment: Nice, yes, when just use the one load, it just has one batch and one RPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
dbSet.Include(p => p.EmailNotices)
     .Include(p => p.EmailTemplatePlaceholders)
     .Include(p => p.Actions)
     .Load();
```

This should result in a single database access that loads all data with a single SELECT.

Answer (score -1):

When using eager loading, Entity Framework will generate a SQL statement that will grab everything in one go, however, if you use Lazy loading, depending on what you want to grab, it will create a separate sql statement for each one.

Comment: I think OP already knows the difference between eager and lazy loading.