# Why is Entity Framework dbSet.Include taking so long to return?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm doing a simple "get" on a table and the "include" part of the routine is taking much longer than I would expect.

I've narrowed the performance issue down to this snippet of code:

```
private List<Task> GetFilteredTasksWithOptionalIncludes(EntityRepository<Task> repo, ITaskRequest model, TaskIncludesModel includes, string accountID)
{
    var includedEntities = new List<Expression<Func<Task, object>>>();

    includedEntities.Add(t => t.Document.Transaction.Account);

    includedEntities.Add(p => p.Signature);

    if (includes != null)
    {
        if (includes.IncludeWorkflowActions)
        {
            includedEntities.Add(p => p.Actions);
        }

        if (includes.IncludeFileAttachments)
        {
            includedEntities.Add(p => p.Attachments);
        }
    }

    IQueryable<Task> tasks = repo.GetAllIncluding(includedEntities.ToArray());  //RETURNS SLOW

    return tasks.ToList();  //RETURNS FAST
}
```

All my  code runs very fast until it hits the repo.GetAllInclude method shown below:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        dbSet.Include(includeProperty).Load();
    }

    return dbSet;
}
```

As I step through the code, it takes up to 6 or 7 seconds for the GetAllIncluded() line to return but it takes less than a second for the tasks.ToList() to return (which is when the actual SQL query gets run so this surprises me).

When I commented out the foreach loop that loads the includes and the entire call returns in under a second.  What causes the includes to take so long?  And is there some better way to do this?

[Here is the SQL Profiler around the call if it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKQaF.jpg)  Everything above the red line is from the GetAllIncluded call.  Everything below the red line is the actual query for the data.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  Doesn't seem like it should take 10 seconds for a fairly simple call.
[image]

Comment: The big part of works is done when you call `Load`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `.Load()` in that loop, you are actually going away to the database and bringing the data into the context.

So depending on how often you are going to that loop, you are running that query over and over.

I would suggest removing the `.Load()` but you can still keep your including function.  A basic Including function for a generic repository would be something like this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Including(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] _includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();
        return _includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
```

And once you have called this and got hold of your `IQueryable`, simply call `.ToList()` on it to only pull from SQL once.

Have a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592911.aspx to see what the Load method is actually doing.

Edit based on your comments:

You could implement the above function I posted and use it similar to what you are doing now, and implicitly calling `Load()` afterwards on the tasks queryable if you want.

```
private List<Task> GetFilteredTasksWithOptionalIncludes(EntityRepository<Task> repo, ITaskRequest model, TaskIncludesModel includes, string accountID)
{
    var includedEntities = new List<Expression<Func<Task, object>>>();

    includedEntities.Add(t => t.Document.Transaction.Account);

    includedEntities.Add(p => p.Signature);

    if (includes != null)
    {
        if (includes.IncludeWorkflowActions)
        {
            includedEntities.Add(p => p.Actions);
        }

        if (includes.IncludeFileAttachments)
        {
            includedEntities.Add(p => p.Attachments);
        }
    }

    IQueryable<Task> tasks = repo.Including(includedEntities.ToArray());  
    tasks.Load();
    return tasks.ToList();  
}
```

Comment: [This is why I started using .Load()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803008/how-do-i-know-that-entity-frameworks-eager-loading-is-working)

Comment: @RichC Ok, but in that example they are adding all their includes, and then calling `.Load()` whereas you are calling `Load()` after each one.

Comment: Ahh - good point!!  I don't think  I was able to loop through them first and then load them for some reason.  I'll look into that.

Comment: There's no point in calling `Load` immediately before calling `ToList`.  The point of `Load`, as your own link states, is to materialize the results of the query without taking the time to construct a `List` object.  One of the two method calls should be removed.

Comment: This is what I get when I do tasks.Load()  `'System.Linq.IQueryable<NameSpaceBlah.Task>' does not contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method 'Load' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<NameSpaceBlah.Task>' could be found`

Comment: Actually, I figured out that if I don't have load on each and every include, it will lazy-load all but the last one (that has the .Load() on it).  I also found that when I'm running a test through the debugger on, that it takes about 4 or 5 times longer than normal.  I haven't dug into this enough to figure out why this is.

Answer (score -1):

Or as an after step to Thewads just write a good old sproc to return all this in multiple sets at once then you can optimise the database schema with appropriate indexes and have it run as fast as possible.

That probably isn't going to be popular but when you start talking db performance it is the quicker way (and easier to work with because you have all the sql tooling for performance tuning) ... eg turn on query execution plans. You might find something insane is happening.

Another question would be ... do you really need *all* this data is there no filter conditions you can apply before you load it all? (assuming you fix the multiple loading issue)

Comment: The developer has the ability to include additional entities along with the task.  By default, no additional entities are included and in that case, the return is super fast.  it just was really odd that it gets up to 10 seconds because some additional entities were included.  There is additional function that allows additional filters (like filter on ID) that I didn't include in the code above for simplicity.

Comment: Post the sql that is being executed and give some kind of indication as to how much and what data if Thewads idea doesn't work. But i suspect that will buy you a ton of time back for now. I dont know if you have 100 rows or 10,000,000. The kind of answer you need changes with the dataset. Still 6.3 seconds for one of those queries is a long time. I suspect you will see some cross joins or some horrid scans. One you look at the queries and the query plans probably you will see the columns being joined on, add covering indexes in the db. But Thewads answer is first as that reduces trips